# Dynamically create checkbox with JQuery from text input

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox

In my cms I have a checkbox group for categories. I would like to have a text input below that where the user can input the name of a new category and it will dynamically add a new checkbox with the provided name used for both the value and the label.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
<div id="cblist">
    <input type="checkbox" value="first checkbox" id="cb1" /> <label for="cb1">first checkbox</label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="ok" id="btnSave" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
        addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
    });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
   var container = $('#cblist');
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;

   $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
   $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The check box gets created perfectly (looked at the generated source using firefox web developer extension) but once the form is submitted with the new checkbox checked it doesn't show in the post variable. Same result for both Safari and Firefox. Any ideas? as i'm stumped.

Comment: is it inside the form? i guess you'd need to give the checkboxes a `name` which i haven't.

Comment: After an hour of banging my head against the wall I would this post which held the answer. Basically had to move the form open tag above the opening div element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445002/cloning-or-adding-an-input-to-a-form-in-jquery-does-not-submit-to-php-in-firefox

Comment: indeed. 'tis what i meant by my question *is it inside the form* ;) sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: that'll teach me for some dodgy markup - thanks again for your help

Comment: @David how to create a maximum of 10 checkbox in rows and 5 checkbox in columns..After it reached 10 checkbox in rows,the next checkbox should start from next column..

Comment: @Manikandan: well, you'll need to count the elements already added, and make the necessary adjustments to your `appendTo` once the current row is full. It shouldn't be very tricky, but it's very different from what was asked here. You should start a new question. Make sure to let people know what you've tried.

Comment: @David Your code has worked for me and i just want to make a little modification by limiting the checkbox as I have mentioned in my previous comment..thanks I will also try like you said..Please do comment if you have any suggestions..

Comment: How can I add <div class="form-check"> around <input> and <label> using this nice way?

Comment: @RobySottini: One way would be to define `var formCheck = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'form-check' }).appendTo(container);` and then change the append target on the input and the label from `container` to `formCheck`. Note that you need the quotes around `class` as class is a reserved keyword in javascript.

Answer (score 8):

One of the elements to consider as you design your interface is on what event (when A takes place, B happens...) does the new checkbox end up being added?

Let's say there is a button next to the text box.  When the button is clicked the value of the textbox is turned into a new checkbox.  Our markup could resemble the following...

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" /> Some label<br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Some other label<br />
</div>

<input type="text" id="newCheckText" /> <button id="addCheckbox">Add Checkbox</button>
```

Based on this markup your jquery could bind to the `click` event of the button and manipulate the DOM.

```
$('#addCheckbox').click(function() {
    var text = $('#newCheckText').val();
    $('#checkboxes').append('<input type="checkbox" /> ' + text + '<br />');
});
```

Comment: I believe you forgot to add the `value` attribute

Answer (score 4):

Put a global variable to generate the ids.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        // Variable to get ids for the checkboxes
        var idCounter=1;
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            var val = $("#txtAdd").val();
            $("#divContainer").append ( "<label for='chk_" + idCounter + "'>" + val + "</label><input id='chk_" + idCounter + "' type='checkbox' value='" + val + "' />" );
            idCounter ++;
        });
    });
</script>
<div id='divContainer'></div>
<input type="text" id="txtAdd" /> 
<button id="btn1">Click</button>
```