# Adding Text to checkbox control in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the this checkbox I'm trying to create in JQuery

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someID">Hello World</input>
```

I thought this was the equivalent JQuery code:

```
var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'checkbox', id: 'someID', text: 'Hello World'})
```

But, when I add the $ctrl to this div tag it seems to not include the 'Hello World' text.

```
$("#renderedControl").append($ctrl);
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: View this link may be help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055459/dynamically-create-checkbox-with-jquery-from-text-input

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
 var $ctrl =  $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
                     id:    'topicFilter-'
                    ,name:  'test'
                    ,value: 'test'
                    ,text :'my testing'
                    ,type:  'checkbox'
                    ,checked:true
            })

var lbl =  '<label>Hello world</label>';


 $("#renderedControl").append($ctrl.after(lbl));
```

Hops its helps

Answer (score 16):

The correct markup for what you're trying to do is this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="someID">Hello World</label>
```

Input elements cannot contain content (and only *require* a closing tag or self-closing in xhtml).

To create the above with jQuery try some variation on this:

```
var $ctrl = $('<label />').html('Hello world')
                          .prepend($('<input/>').attr({ type: 'checkbox', id: 'someID'}));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bwxza/

Answer (score 1):

first  if you want to create the check box do it like this

```
$("#renderedControl").append('<input type="checkbox" id="someID"/>');
```

Notices that html of the check should be define like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example" id="someID" />
```

If you want to set a label you have to create a element for that checkbox like this, the reason behind that you cannot see the Hellow world it's not correct of use text to set a label for a checkbox and I think it's not even a valid attribute for that type. Here's an example of the html related to a label for that checkbox

```
<label for="example">Hellow world</label>
```

And then append all the html related like this

```
$("#renderedControl").append('<label for="checkbox">Hellow world</label>').append('<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="someID" />')
```

At the end you could create something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/ynMK8/

Answer (score 1):

`<input />` elements aren't pairs of tags. They are self-closing:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someID" name="someName" value="input" />
```

With jQuery, you can do this:

```
$('<input />', {
    'type': 'checkbox',
    'id': 'someID',
    'name': 'someName'
}).after($('<label />', {
    'for': 'someName'
}).text('Hello World')).appendTo('body');​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KNnUt/**

Comment: Hey I want to give some style to label too. what is the syntax for doing it?