# Error create selectbox in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="item"></div>
var div = $('<div/>', {
   style : 'border-top: 1px dotted #ccc; margin: 4px; padding: 10px;'
}).appendTo($('#item'));
var select = $('<select/>',{
   name : 'name[]',
   option: {
      value : 1,
      value : 2
   }
}).appendTo(div);
```

=> error can't create value for select box

How to fix it, with this result:

```
<select name="name[]">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This question should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055459/dynamically-create-checkbox-with-jquery-from-text-input

Comment: Try to append option tags to your select element

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var div = $('<div></div>').css({'border-top': '1px dotted #ccc', 'margin': '4px', 'padding': '10px'});

var select = $('<select/>')
.attr('name','name[]')
.append('<option value=1>My option</option>')
.append('<option value=2>My option</option>')
.appendTo(div);

div.appendTo($('#item'));


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would do stuff like this :

```
var div = $('<div/>')
    .css({
        borderTop : '1px dotted #ccc',
        margin : '4px',
        padding : '10px'
    });

div.appendTo( $('#item') );

var opts = {
    value_1 : 'value #1',
    value_2 : 'value #2',
    value_3 : 'value #3'
};
var select = $('<select/>').attr( 'name', 'name[]' );

$.each(opts, function( k, v ){
    // k is the key from opts, ex : value_1
    // v is the value attributet to k, ex : value #1
    $('<option />', {
        text : v,
        value : k
    }).appendTo( select );
});

select.appendTo( div );
```

According to your project, you can populate the "opts" object from ajax or whatever you want

[Example here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/m6ZyF/)

Also, for that div i would add a class instead adding the css inline. It will be easier to modify in time