# How can i append checkboxes to my ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create checkboxes dynamically for the data received from database.

jQuery and AJAX call:

```
$("#destinationName").autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showDestinations",
            type: "POST",
            data : { term : request.term },
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<label>Destination</label>
<input type="text" id="destinationName" name="destinationName" value="${Form.destinationName}" class="field" />
```

Response received when I kept alert:

```
[ "abc", "def"]
```

Kindly provide your valuable suggestions. Being new to AJAX and jQuery I am facing a tough time in getting this result.

Comment: is that one expected response?

Comment: You might try checking out this answer.  It talks about using jQuery to create check boxes using text input.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055459/dynamically-create-checkbox-with-jquery-from-text-input

Comment: autocomplete functionality was set to the destination field. My new requirement is to add checkboxes to this autofunctionality, so that i can select multiple checkboxes. hope you got my point.

Comment: @Jalal is the checkbox created based on response from server?

Comment: @aktiv: i am using jquery autocomplete and ajax call. once i enter a character or string in the destination text box, it should retrieve the list of destinations for the entered format by querying the DB2. till now its fine, All I need is check box functionality for the existing scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
success: function(data) {
  $("#resultDiv").html("");
  $.each(data, function(i, record) {
    $("#resultDiv").append("<input type='checkbox' id='chk-" + i + "' name='" + record + "' /> " + record);
  });
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, however, my result is not changing according to the text or string being entered. the result displays only for the first time with check boxes and it does not change upon the input.

Comment: On what event are you calling this ajax?

Comment: i am using jquery autocomplete. when i enter M or M.COM , all the results including this letter or text will be displayed as auto suggestion. I want the same functionality with checkboxes.

Comment: I see, usually, $("#resultDiv").html(""); should see to it that your div is cleaned up. for autocomplete I think you may be using the keyup function or something. Make sure the div where the results appear is cleaned up on your next search

Comment: for the check boxes, instead of giving name as a dynamic record, can I make it as a constant value, in order to retrieve the checked results on the controller side?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this** : http://jsfiddle.net/4wf3rq04/

```
    use $.each(function(){...})
```

Comment: its not allowing me to accept more than one answer :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != null) {

                    var temp = data.d;

                    if (temp != '') {

                        var Response = temp.split(",");

                        if ((Response != '') && (Response.length > 0)) {

                            for (i = 0; i < Response.length; i++) {
                                $("#resultDiv").append("<input type='checkbox' id='chk-" + i + "' name='" + Response[i] + "' /> " + Response[i]);

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```