# add new text field, select and checkbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic

I'm trying to make a form in HTML/Javascript/PHP with a **select list** a **check box** and a **text field** plus **one add button**.

this form have to work like this:

- Step1 When the page is loaded the text fields have to be disabled and select
  field is active
- Step2 When I select the checkbox, the text field is
  enabled and select is disabled.
- Step3 When I press the add button, it should add: 1 checkbox, 1 text field and 1 select option.

Everything works correctly until I press the add button. Initial fields work well but the ones added do not.I mean step 1 and 2 is not anymore execute when I press checkbox.

My PHP and HTML

```
<hr><div class="container1">
<button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "ckautor[]" checked = "ckautor" onclick = "f_autor(this.checked)">Adauga Autor:<br />                   
<div><select name = "select_aut[]" id = "select_aut" >
                    <?php
                        $select_autor = mysqli_query(conectare(), "SELECT nume_autor FROM autor");
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_autor)){
                            ?><option><?php
                        echo $row["nume_autor"];
                        ?></option><?php    
                        }
                    ?>
</select></div>                     
        <p>Autor:</br>
            <input type = "text" name = "nume_autor[]" id = "nume_autor" size = "40" disabled = "disabled"></p>
</div><hr>
```

My JavaScript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type = "checkbox" name = "ckautor[]" checked = "ckautor" onclick = "f_autor(this.checked)">Adauga Autor:<br /><div><select name = "select_aut[]"><?php $select_autor = mysqli_query(conectare(), "SELECT nume_autor FROM autor");while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_autor)){ ?> <option> <?php echo $row["nume_autor"]; ?> </option> <?php } ?></select> </div> <input type="text" name="nume_autor[]" size = "33" disabled = "disabled"/><a href="#" class="delete"> Delete </a> </div>'); //add input box
        }
  else
  {
  alert('Maximum limit is 10!')
  }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function f_autor(ckautor){
    if(!ckautor){
        document.getElementById('select_aut').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('nume_autor').disabled = false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('select_aut').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('nume_autor').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055459/dynamically-create-checkbox-with-jquery-from-text-input

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript/

Comment: Using JQuery:
`$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  // Does some stuff and logs the event to the console
});`

Comment: @Pang sorry about that. I just read it...