# Mutiple check boxes based on output using javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider that i have a variable var=output[] and this output will sometimes have one output or multiple outputs. Now, i want to create a checkbox based on the output.
If the out is of one then one checkbox has to be created with output name and if if the output is multiple then multiple check boxes has to created with output names. Please help me out and can you make it just JavaScript and not with any another.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear, please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Unfortunatly i havent tried anything. I do not know where to start all i have is a output and some output will be of one that is output = cat and then i have create a checkbox with cat name next to it. sometimes ouput will be multiple like cat,dog,snake and then 3 checkboxes has to be created.

Comment: i believe this is what your looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055459/dynamically-create-checkbox-with-jquery-from-text-input

Comment: yes kind of and the code is in jqueary i guess. Can i get the same code in pure javascript? I am pretty new javascript..

Comment: Instead of using jquery, just use getElementbyId().innerHTML and add the actual text of the checkbox, like "<input type='checkbox'/>".

Answer (score 0):

Heres the code in javascript

```
<div id="cblist">
      <input type="checkbox" value="first checkbox" id="cb1" /> <label for="cb1">first checkbox</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" value="ok" onClick="addCheckbox()" id="btnSave" />

       function addCheckbox(name) {
          var container = document.getElementById('cblist');
          var name = document.getElementById('txtName').value

          var input = document.createElement("input");
          input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
          input.setAttribute("value", name);
          input.setAttribute("name", 'cb' + name);
          container.appendChild(input);

          var label = document.createElement("label");
          label.htmlFor = "cb" + name;
          label.innerHTML = name;
          container.appendChild(label);

        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/31u8eszd/5/